# Length of open set

Tags: measure-theory

Question:- $G_1$ and $G_2$ are open sets in  $[a,b]$, $G_1 \subseteq G_2$ then show that the length of $G_1$ is less than or equal to length of $G_2$.

I take random open interval $(a,b)$ as $G_1$ and $(c,d)$ as $G_2$ and with help of inequality i proved it but subject teacher said it is just one particular case, give more general solution.

Somewere i saw hint like take $G_1$ and $G_2$ as union of open sets and then try to prove.

Any idea how to prove !!

Comment: How do you define length?

Answer (score 0):

We know that the lebesgue measure is a generalization of length in the real line an it is inner regular,i.e:

$m(A)=\inf \{m(O)| O$ is open and $A \subseteq O \}$

Thus $m(G_1)= \inf \{m(O)| O$ is open and $G_1 \subseteq O \} \leqslant m(G_2)$
because $G_2$ is an open set containing $G_1$.

This is one way to prove it.

Remember that the lebesgue measure is the restriction of the lebesgue outer measure $m^*$ is the sigma algebra of the lebesgue measurable sets,and we also know that $m^*((a,b))=b-a$.

Also remember that every open set in the real line is a union of disjoint open intervals.